# Modifying table of contents' entry fonts

Tags: table-of-contents

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Section title}
Section text

\subsection{Subsection title}
Subsection text

\end{document}
```

How can I italicize the font of "Subsection title" in the table of contents? (not in the document body)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\renewcommand{\cftsubsecfont}{\itshape}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecpresnum}{\upshape}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Section title}
Section text

\subsection{Subsection title}
Subsection text

\end{document}
```

[image: tocloft sample]

See §2.3 of [the `tocloft` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tocloft/tocloft.pdf#subsection.2.3) for more details.

Answer (score 4):

You can remodify the definition of the command `\cftsubsecfont` which controls the output of subsection title

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecfont}{\itshape}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Section title}
Section text

\subsection{Subsection title}
Subsection text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You beat me to it by one minute, because I also set the subsection number upright and linked to the manual.

Comment: I hope my first comment didn’t sound too whiny. It’s a good answer, and I upvoted it!

Comment: @Davislor Don't worry about that, your answer is obviously better.

Comment: Very kind of you to say. If I’d seen yours first, I’d have made my own additions as comments.