# How to change style of section titles

Tags: fonts

As a follow-up question to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/554104/modifying-table-of-contents-entry-fonts/554109) question, how can I get "Subsection title" below into italics and not bold? I do not want to change "Subsection title" in the table of contents, nor do I want to change the font of "Subsection text."

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Section title}
Section text

\subsection{Subsection title}
Subsection text

\end{document}
```

I have read through the titlesec documentation, but I am struggling to decipher it.

Comment: Just declare in the preamble `\titleformat*{\subsection}{\large\itshape\mdseries}`.

Comment: There is a package called "sectsty" https://ctan.org/pkg/sectsty

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you run either

```
\usepackage{sectsty}
\subsectionfont{\mdseries\itshape}
```

or (as already suggested by @Bernard)

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\large\itshape\mdseries
```

in the preamble. Note: load either `titleformat` or `secsty`, *but not both*.

Both methods shown above will render the subsection header text *and* the associated subsection number in italics. If you want the subsection number to be rendered in an upright font shape, I suggest you also include the following code in the preamble:

```
\makeatletter % See pp. 26f. of 'The LaTeX Companion,' 2nd ed.
\def\@seccntformat#1{\@ifundefined{#1@cntformat}%
   {\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}%    default appearance
   {\csname #1@cntformat\endcsname}}% enable individual control
\newcommand\subsection@cntformat{\upshape\thesubsection\quad} % subsection level 
\makeatother
```

A full MWE and its output:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\usepackage{sectsty}
\subsectionfont{\mdseries\itshape}

% See pp. 26f. of 'The LaTeX Companion,' 2nd ed. 
\makeatletter
\def\@seccntformat#1{\@ifundefined{#1@cntformat}%
   {\csname the#1\endcsname\quad}%    default appearance
   {\csname #1@cntformat\endcsname}}% enable individual control
\newcommand\subsection@cntformat{\upshape\thesubsection\quad} % subsection level 
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Section title}
Section text

\subsection{Subsection title}
Subsection text
\end{document}
```